# Getting Vim to recognize XML

Tags: xml, vim, indentation, vi

I would like Vim to help me indent my XML files like my C code. However, when I use

```
gg=G
```

It just sets everything to the left. Do I need to designate a syntax? Is XML recognized as a language?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Put

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

in your `.vimrc` to have Vim automatically identify .xml files as xml. You might need to put

```
set nocompatible
```

before that.

If the file extension is not .xml, you can make Vim threat it like xml by using

```
:set filetype=xml
```

After you do that, Vim's autoindention (and syntax highlighting, and omnicomplete (that in xml just closes tags, but that's still something)) will work properly for xml.

Comment: Running Vim in compatible mode is like running old vi... which is kind of the point of compatible mode, but it's just sad that that's the default.

Comment: If you are editing FXML in javaFX, the `:set filetype=xml` command brings blessed syntax coloring to your file.  Sweet!

Comment: or shorter `:setf xml` (found somewhere and it works for me)

Answer (score 6):

Yep, `:set syntax=xml` should work.  In vim 7.3, this sets `:set indentexpr=XmlIndentGet(v:lnum,1)`.

If you've got a one-line file, you may need to `:%s/\(<[^>]*>\)/\1\r/g`, to insert newlines after every tag (or split it differently).

Then, `gg=G` should work.

Comment: I'm running a pretty old version of Fedora Core :(  Stuck with vim 7.2, so I don't get auto indent.

Comment: @IslandCow I don't think that this matters. You just need to get `indent/xml.vim` from vim-7.3 runtime if you don't have `XmlIndentGet` function. I don't see anything vim-7.3-specific in this file.

Comment: XML syntax seems to work fine in 7.2 on Windows.  As a user you shouldn't have to worry about the indentexpr, as long as syntax is set right you should be fine.  (Although you might try `:set filetype=xml` instead, too.)

Comment: For a slightly easier command for individual line splitting, I use: :s/>/>\r/g  i.e. substitute(:s) for every >(xml end tag) a >(xml end tag)with a newline(>\r) (g stands for global (in the line)).  This will leave a new line after each end tag that already had a new line but is fast and easy to remember.

Comment: I don't want newlines after EVERY tag, just the CLOSING tags. Tweaked regex: `:%s/\(<\/[^>]*>\)/\1\r/g`

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your .vimrc file:

```
:map <Space>fx :%s/\ </\r</g<cr>:%s/\ android/\randroid/g<cr>:g/^$/d<cr>gg=G`
```

to format click `space fx`