# Vim: Making XML text “pretty”

Tags: xml, editor, vi, text-processing, text-formatting

Is there an easy way within `vi` to make your XML text "pretty"?

For example:

I want this..

```
            <person>
  <name>Nick</name>
 <age>26</age>

         <gender>male</gender>
<occupation>doctor</occupation>

    </person>
```

to be this (including the spaces)...

```
<person>

    <name>Nick</name>
    <age>26</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
    <occupation>doctor<occupation>

</person>
```

I've tried using these commands within `vi`:

```
:set filetype=xml
:filetype indent on
gg=G
```

But it just removes all of my indentation I had. So now, everything look like this:

```
<person>
<name>Nick</name>
<age>26</age>
<gender>male</gender>
<occupation>doctor</occupation>
</person>
```

Comment: See the following question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600860/getting-vim-to-recognize-xml

Comment: One issue with the xml you provided is that the occupation tag is not properly closed. If it is a well formed XML, vim should do its job given the options you tried.